# Mongo compass connects and shows 0 dbs, but my node js project can connect and queries return everything

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-compass

So, I've been using compass and nodejs to connect to my db for some time. I've noticed a new GUI for compass few days ago.
My problem is I can connect through both, but since a couple days through compass, once connected, it shows 0 db, while my queries results are all correct, so it's all there, but compass can't seem to detect it.

I've tried either a simple connection without any option up and with options (replicaSet&readPreference&ssl&authMechanism on both nodejs and compass, while it works well on node, it doesn't either way on compass.

I'll attach a screen of my connection string if it could be of any help understanding my issue.

[connection string through compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gnht.png)